# How can I print a scalable pyramid in size determined with user input?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm taking a beginners Java course over the summer. I need to make a pyramid using loops for homework. The pyramid has to be made out of asterisks; in addition, size of pyramid is determined by user.

This is what I have for code now;

```
public class Pyramid {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int size = 6;
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int y = x; y < size; y++) {

        }
        for (int z = 0; z <= x; z++) {
            System.out.print("*");

        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

The problem of my code is that the number of asterisks in each row is wrong by one.

Comment: `I need to make a pyramid` At first I read that as you had to make one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid), and was surprised. Then I read `[t]he pyramid has to be made out of asterisks`, and thought ["ahh, a challenge!"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk_(PBX)). Constructing a pyramid using only copies of PBX software- I like the way your teacher thinks.

Comment: ...All jokes aside, I'm seeing X, Y, and Z in the code. Does your teacher actually expect you to render a 3D ASCII image? Or when you say 'pyramid' do you more accurately mean 'triangle'? Or was I right the first time around and you're expected to painstakingly haul slabs of stone in service to the Pharaoh?

Comment: @ParthianShot I think the plan is that they're supposed to generate a triangle from asterisks.  Then the teacher will print 1,000 copies of each triangle, bundle the printouts into sheaves to make bricks, and make the students painstakingly haul the printout bricks to Egypt...

Comment: Oh I didn't even think of it that way. No I dont have to make a 3D rendering, I just like to use x as my variable and then I go down the alphabet until z and then I start with a.

Comment: @ajb `bundle the printouts into sheaves to make bricks` We know from science that any comment containing that phrase was going to get an upvote from me. Proof of determinism in the universe.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int z = 0; z <= x; z++) {
```

will execute the loop until `z <= x` is no longer true.  That means it executes for `z=0`, `z=1`, `z=2`, ..., `z=x`--which means it actually executes the loop `x+1` times.  (The next `z`, `z=x+1`, is the first `z` that makes `z<=x` false.)

The normal idiom in Java (and other language with C-like `for` statements) is to start at 0 and use `<` when checking for the upper bound:

```
for (int z = 0; z < x; z++) {
```

You'll run into cases where you want to use `<=`, and you'll run into cases where you want to start at 1 instead of 0, but the majority of `for` loops with an integer index follow this form.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly :

```
 public class Pyramid  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int size =6;
       for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
           for (int x = size - 1; x >= i; x--) {
               System.out.print(" ");
           }

           for (int y = 1; y<= i; y++) {
               System.out.print("*");
           }

           for (int z= 1; z <= i - 1; z++) {
               System.out.print("*");
           }

           System.out.println();
       }
     }
   }
```

The output is :

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could do something like this

```
int levels = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (levels < 1) {
    System.out.println("What size triangle would you like?");
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        levels = input.nextInt();
    } else if (input.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid size: " + input.next());
    } else {
        System.err.println("no more input");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i <= levels; i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int t = i;
    while (--t > 0) {
        sb.append("*");
    }
    StringBuilder spaces = new StringBuilder();
    for (t = 0; t < levels - i; t++) {
        spaces.append(' ');
    }
    System.out.println(spaces.toString() + sb + "*" + sb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem it's best to think about the numbers that go into it...

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

If you label the parts of the triangle

```
  *     row 1, 2 spaces, 1 star
 ***    row 2, 1 space, 3 stars
*****   row 3, 0 spaces, 5 starts
```

Then you can just start playing with the numbers
The number of spaces to display is 3 - row # + 1
The number of stars to display is 2 * row - 1

Then construct a loop to draw each line.
   within this loop, you need a loop to draw the number of spaces
   and a loop to draw the number of stars